# Am I under a ban after being detained and removed from the UK?

Tags: uk, overstaying, removal

I visited the UK 10 times in my life and never overstayed. On the 11th journey to the UK in 2016, I was arrested because I overstayed 15 days.

I was sure that I was not in breach of the UK law because there are two notations on the visa sticker. The first one says *visa granted from:.../.../.... to .../.../....* and the second says *validity of the stay: 180 days.*

In my honest understanding, I was convinced that the countdown started from the date of entry and not from the date of issuance of the visa. Hence my mistake, but it was made in good faith.

By the way, I made 10 trips before without ever breaking any rule or British law. When I was arrested, I was 58 years old. I did not intend to stay in the UK illegally when I was very young, why would I do so at 58 years old? It's nonsense! I am 60 years old today.

Is there a chance to revoke a ban, if any, and, if so, how? What should I do or say, whom do I contact?

Comment: You should have been given paperwork when you were removed. What does it say?

Comment: If you don't have any documents you can post, maybe you can explain better what happened in 2016. Were you arrested at the airport trying to enter? That sounds incorrect, as you would just be refused entry (I believe).

Comment: @krim belkacem Were you given written notification of a ban? 15 days overstay, although a breach, seems too small to attract a ban although it may well make it harder for you to get a visa in future

Comment: If there is a ban you cannot revoke it. You can appeal etc but not **revoke**. That’s not the right word. In any case you sound incoherent. Explain more clearly what happened.

Comment: Where were you arrested? Also before 24th November 2016, overstays less than 28 days were disregarded under normal circumstances. When were you removed?

Comment: How long before the visa expired did you enter, and how many days, total, were you in the UK before you were detained? What terms does your removal order state?

Comment: You say it's "nonsense" to imagine that you would break the law now, because you didn't break the law when you were younger. Don't you realise how ridiculous that sounds?

Comment: My visa was valid from: 15/12/2015 until: 15/06/2016. I came to UK on the 18th of March 2016. I was arrested on the 26th of June 2016. Spent 4 days in custody and was put in retention center 10 days exactly. I was asked if I wanted to apply for asylum and I refused, if I needed a solicitor and I refused. The 11th of July 2016 I was put in a plane with my own prepaid flight ticket towards Algiers. Very angry I destroyed all papers they gave me. As far as I remember the document said that: "I might be banned". I thank you all for your kind answers!

Comment: I don't think that what I said is ridiculous. Usually, people who transgress the immigration law aim to settle in the country they are in. When young, they may hope build a new life, marry a British or European girl...etc... in resume, build a new life. It is a bit harder to do so when you are 60, don't you think? Especially when you have had the chance to do it before when you were far more younger. I visited UK 10 times before while I was: 16, 24, 25, 37, 38, 42 year old and never overstayed when it was easier for me to marry and settle. Why should I do that when I am 60? At 60 game is over!

Comment: I left UK voluntarily but after being put into a Retention center...So is it correct to say you left "voluntarily" when being in detention? Does that not mean "forcibly removed"? Please explain me, I am so confused about these 2 terms! Thanks again all of you.

Comment: @krim belkacem Something about your story does not add up. What were you arrested for - a crime or overstaying? The latter seems unlikely for relatively few days, were you working illegally? Was your visa curtailed in any way when you entered the U.K.?

Comment: Traveller: No, I have never committed the tinniest offense against the law in the UK  nor anywhere else. I am from a very well educated family (late father was a Consul General of Algeria to Paris) and I have been a teacher for long years in Algeria. I was caught at Marble Arch  station when aiming to reach the Algerian airline agency too book my return flight when I had a problem with my underground pass (no credit enough) 2 policemen were there and one of them asked me to show him my ID. I shown him my passport fully confident my visa was still valid. He didn't agree and took me to custody.

Comment: Traveller: My visa has never been curtailed in any way and I had my own money and never worked illegally.

Answer (score 10):

You breached the conditions of your visa and were caught. Whether you were arrested or detained, it is likely you would have been served an order for administrative removal. The document you received would indicate any applicable re-entry ban, e.g., 12 months if you left the UK voluntarily and at your own expense.

If you are unclear about whether you are barred from entering the UK for any period of time, you could make a [Request personal information held in the borders, immigration and citizenship system](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration).

The removal order would also advise your rights, although, in general, a breach of a UK visa issued for 6 months or less, e.g, the Standard Visitor visa, does not have a right of appeal attached to it.

Comment: Reading this may also help the OP’s understanding https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf

Comment: Traveller: Let me please resume my main question as clearly as possible:

Comment: Traveller: Thanks and let me please explain as clearly as possible my main question:

Comment: My main question is as follow: I was arrested, put in custody then in a detention center. I have never refuse to leave UK but on the contrary asked to be sent back to my country as soon as possible. I traveled on my own expenses. Does the fact I was in detention mean that I have been removed forcibly (though I asked for depart) or voluntarily (despite I was in detention)? Because being forced means 10 years ban and voluntarily depart is subject to 1 to 5 years ban. This is what I want to know. And many thanks again.

Comment: @krimbelkacem please understand that this site is not a forum, so we don't go back and forth in comments. You were told to leave, you did so, and your removal order tells you for how long your ban is in place, and no one here can determine that. Depending on *your* circumstances, it could be 1 year (or 5, or 10): look at the document and, if you don't have it, use the link in the answer to ask the UKVI.

Comment: Traveller: I do thank you for your help but, I unfortunately did not find what I'm looking for: My crucial question is : Am I considered as volunteer departer though I am already in detention? Or do I have to ask for a voluntarily departure only at a condition I am fre (not in detention). And the different links don't explicit the exact meaning of "Voluntarily". But thanks agin for your kindness.